Multiple time dimensions and understanding ultrahyperbolic differential equations
On article "On the dimensionality of spacetime (https://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/dimensions.pdf) Max Tegmark writes about ultrahyperbolic differential equations leading to unpredictability:

"If an observer is to be able to make any use of its self-awareness and
information-processing abilities, the laws of physics must be such that it can make at
least some predictions. Specifically, within the framework of a field theory, it should, by
measuring various nearby field values, be able to compute field values at some more distant
spacetime points (ones lying along its future world line being particularly useful) with non infinite error bars."

He also writes that

"The last requirement means that the solution $u$ at a given point will only change by a finite amount if the boundary data is changed by a finite amount. Therefore, even if an ill-posed problem can be formally solved, this solution would in practice be useless to an observer, since it would need to measure the initial data with infinite accuracy to be able to place finite error bars on the solution (any measurement error would cause the error bars on the solution to be infinite)."

So, if I understand correctly, he states that these equations are extremely sensitive to small changes in boundary conditions. Equation would yield very different results with boundary conditions like $y(0)=0$ or $y(0)=10^{-10}$? I am having hard time to understand what this really means. Does this mean that if I would plug any ultrahyperbolic differential equation to some numerical solver, I would get wildly different behavior with small changes in boundary conditions. Is there any intuition or numerical examples of such behavior?
